# On Facebook, is there a way to stop notifications of posts of an event to which you've been invited?

Tags: facebook, notifications

Until now I always get notified when someone writes on an event I haven't even taken a look at.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried going to:
`Account Settings` > `Notifications` > `Events`

Make sure all of the appropriate check marks are checked/unchecked and see if that does it.